# Can't extract data from controller for angular-chosen

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I need to use [angular-chosen](https://github.com/localytics/angular-chosen) to customize a drop-down of groups for a project. I use resource to share the data between the controllers. I am able to extract the group list to 
$scope.allgroups of my controller. The console.log shows me this image :

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QFyE3Zq.png]

In my html, I do call the select in the following way but It always shows "No Group Found.." even with matching characters.

```
<select
    chosen multiple style="width:150px;" id="newusergroups"
    class="groupselect" title="Groups"
    allow-single-deselect="true"
    data-placeholder="Select Group.."
    no-result-text="No Such Group.."
    ng-model="selectedgroup"
    ng-options="pergroup.name for pergroup in allgroups">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

Anywhere I am wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the screenshot shows the console.log of `allgroups`, then your ng-options should be `ng-options="pergroup.name for pergroup in allgroups.result"`, OR `allgroups = $myResource.result`.